# Place Colorbar to One Side of GeoAxes Plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, figure, colorbar, cartopy

I am generating a irregular gridded plot with a globe projection and am utilizing both xarray and CartoPy to achieve this. The following minimal code produces the first image below, note that I am leaving out calling specific packages and specifically defined cmap/norm options, as they remain outside the bounds of my question:

```
file = '/path/to/data/griddeddata.tif'
da = rxr.open_rasterio(file)
da = ((da * 1.8) + 32)

ny, nx = len(da['y']), len(da['x'])
x, y = np.meshgrid(da['x'], da['y'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
ax = plt.subplot(projection=crs.LambertConformal())
ax.set_extent([-75.500000, -72.000000, 40.500000, 43.000000], crs=crs.LambertConformal())

im = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, da.variable.data[0], cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((14, 8))
plt.gca().set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

[image: Correct Image Without Colorbar]

When I add the following code `plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax, pad=0.01, ticks=[-50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120], aspect=40)`, I get a colorbar that appears inside the map plot itself, whereas I would like this colorbar to be oriented vertically to the right.

[image: Correct Image With Improperly Placed Colorbar]

I suspect that this has to do with the sharing of a georeferenced axis (map plot) and an unreferenced colorbar axis, though I am unsure how to correct the issue. What additional steps are recommended to take in order to achieve the desired result? Thanks!

Comment: If you make the axes fill the figure, where do you expect the colorbar to go?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create additonal axis besides the plot for the colorbar.
The following code can be adjusted to your need.

1. Define the position

   ```
   cbar_pos = [0.90, 0.30, 0.03, 0.45]   #axis for colorbar left, bottom, width, height
   ```
2. Create the axis

   ```
   cbar_ax = fig.add_axes(cbar_pos)              
   cbar_ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False) 
   cbar_ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')  
   cbar_ax.set_yticklabels([])
   cbar_ax.tick_params(size=0)`
   ```
3. Pass the `cbar_ax` into your `colorbar` function

   ```
   plt.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax, pad=0.01, ticks=[-50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120], aspect=40)
   ```